# URL Rewrite /index.php?page=sample to /sample.htm

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

very new to .htaccess, don't completely understand most of it.  Anyway, the intention is to rewrite /index.php?page=sample to sample.htm. (or any other page)

The script below seems to work partly.  If I type /sitemap.htm it does display that page but the address bar changes to /index.php?page=sitemap.  How can I rewrite the url into a more friendly one so that when I enter /sitemap.htm the address stays that way and when I type /index.php?page=sitemap it will redirect to /sitemap.htm but still works?

Apologies if i sound confusing.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+getreal\.co\.uk/index\.php\?page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.htm? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.htm?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. But `THE_REQUEST` doesn't contain domain name.

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=((?!login\b)[^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.htm? [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.htm$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, this does changed the url but it goes into a loop error : 'This web page has a redirect loop'

Comment: Fixed it now. Didn't realize you have `R=301` in 2nd rule also.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thanks a lot. this works.  I have another issue though.  After applying this I can no longer login/register to the site.  Is there a way to ignore /index.php?page=login  ?